# Polymer Core-Ajax seems to be running it event handler twice, Is this a bug?

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I have two core-ajax elements in my template.  It "appears" that the event handler that is on the first core-ajax is running as a result of BOTH core-completes.  Here is what I got..

```
<polymer-element name="pmg-report" attributes="columnSetup">
<template>

    <div id="rptTitle" class="rpt-page-head">This is the Report Page</div>

    <core-ajax auto url="/reports/report1b.txt"
               params=''
               handleas="text"
               on-core-response="{{handleRptSetupResponse}}"
    </core-ajax>

    <core-ajax auto url="/webservices/reportsws.asmx/Get_Report1"
               params=''
               handleas="json"
               on-core-response="{{handleGetReportResponse}}"
               method="post"
               contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8">
    </core-ajax>

    <div class="pgm-test">
        <template repeat="{{group in groups}}">
            <pmg-group groupid={{group.id}}></pmg-group>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
    <script>

        Polymer('pmg-report', {

            handleRptSetupResponse: function (e) {
                var theR = e.detail.response;
                console.log('handleRptSetup->', e.detail.response);
                var jsColSetup = JSON.parse(theR);
                rptSetup = jsColSetup;

            },

            handleGetReportResponse: function (e) {

                var theData = JSON.parse(e.detail.response.d);
                var cols = Object.keys(theData[0]);

                //Setup global Columns list
                for (cnt = 0 ; cnt < cols.length ; cnt++) {
                    columns.push({ name: cols[cnt] });
                }

                //Process data.
                for (cnt = 0; cnt < theData.length; cnt++) {
                    theData[cnt].id = cnt + 1;

                    if ( cnt < 100 ) {
                        dispRows.push(theData[cnt]);
                    }

                }

                console.log('dispRows.length (rpt)->', dispRows.length);

                this.groups = [
                    { id: 1 },
                    { id: 2 }
                ];

                this.$.rptTitle.innerHTML = rptSetup.title;

            },
```

...

So what is happening to me is that when the "handleRptSetup" method is getting executed when both ajax-core calls happen.  The "handleGetReportResponse" is only getting executed one time.  The second e.detail.response returned to "handleRptSetup" is the one intended for "handleGetReportResponse".  "handleGetReportResponse" is executing only one time and is getting the correct response.

So I'm wondering if this is a bug?  Or am I not understanding something here?

Comment: Your first `<core-ajax` is missing it's closing `>`. Check your live code for this problem.

Comment: Holly crap...  Moral of this story don't post questions at the end of the day!  Thank you so much for finding my stupidity!